# SQL View without references

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view

We have in SQL Server 2008 R2 a table `T` with 20 columns. Four columns are simple foreign keys from four other fixed `(ID, Value)` tables.

All we want now, is to create a new VIEW with those four `foreign-key-columns` of `T` replaced by those corresponding `Values`. 16 remaining columns should be untouched.

Please, how to achieve that in `SQL` in the most elegant way?

Comment: Are you trying to create a view that has something "elegant" like `SELECT (* except for these 4 columns)` rather than listing out the other 16 columns individually? Why? If it's something else, can you explain what you want to be "elegant" that would be different from the normal way you would join such tables?

Comment: If you want decent answers, please *list* the 20 column names and tell us which columns point to which of the other four tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply join the 4 related tables there isn't a shorthand way of doing it;

```
SELECT
  T1.Value as T1Value,
  ...
  T4.Value as T4Value,
  T.fld1
  ..
  T.fld16
FROM
  T
INNER JOIN T1 ON T.T1_ID = T1.ID
...
INNER JOIN T4 ON T.T4_ID = T4.ID
```

Comment: You probably want to alias the 4 "Value" columns so the view doesn't have 4 identical column names.

Comment: @James that makes no sense. If there are four columns in the main table, they can't all be named ID.

Comment: No, mea culpa, you're right. They're named, say, Id1,Id2 etc.